# Spring: one JPA model, many JSON respresentations

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm writing a RESTful web service using Spring/JPA. There's a JPA model which is exposed through the web service. The 'Course' model is quite spacious - it actually is composed of several sets of data: general information, pricing details and some caches.

The issue I encounter is the inability to issue different JSON representations using the same JPA model.

The in first case I only need to return `general_info` set of data for courses:

`GET /api/courses/general_info`

in the second case I would like to return `pricing` set of data only:

`GET /api/courses/pricing`

I see the following ways to solve this, not in particular order:

1. To create `CourseGeneralInfo` and `CoursePricing` JPA models using
   the origin database table as a source. `CourseGeneralInfo` model
   would have its own set of fields and `CoursePricing` would have its
   own ones. This way I would have the JSON I need.
2. To refactor the stuff out of the Course model/table to have
   GeneralInfo and PricingDetails to be separate JPA entities. Ok, this sounds like the best one (imo) though the database is legacy and it is not something I can change easily...
3. Leverage some sort of DTO and [Spring Mappers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/previews/mapping.html) to convert the JPA model to representation needed in any particular case.

What approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Data REST 2.1 there is a new mechanism for this purpose - Projections (It's now part of spring-data-commons).

You'll need to define interface, containing exactly exposed fields:

```
@Projection(name = "summary", types = Course.class)
interface CourseGeneralInfo {

  GeneralInfo getInfo();

}
```

After that Spring will be able to find it automagically in your source, and you could make requests to your existing endpoints, like this:

```
GET /api/courses?projection=general_info
```

Based on 
https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra

Spring sample project with projections:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/projections

Answer (score 3):

I was just reading about some really nifty features in Spring 4.1, which allow you to use different views via annotations.

from: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

```
public class View {
    interface Summary {}
}

public class User {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String firstname;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String lastname;

    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
}

public class Message {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private LocalDate created;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String title;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private User author;

    private List<User> recipients;

    private String body;
}
```

Thanks to Spring MVC `@JsonView` support, it is possible to choose, on a per handler method basis, which field should be serialized:

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return messageService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Message getMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return messageService.get(id);
    }
}
```

In this example, if all messages are retrieved, only the most important fields are serialized thanks to the `getAllMessages()` method annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)`:

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "created" : "2014-11-14",
  "title" : "Info",
  "author" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "firstname" : "Brian",
    "lastname" : "Clozel"
  }
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "created" : "2014-11-14",
  "title" : "Warning",
  "author" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstname" : "Stéphane",
    "lastname" : "Nicoll"
  }
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "created" : "2014-11-14",
  "title" : "Alert",
  "author" : {
    "id" : 3,
    "firstname" : "Rossen",
    "lastname" : "Stoyanchev"
  }
} ]
```

In Spring MVC default configuration, `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` is set to false. That means that when enabling a JSON View, non annotated fields or properties like body or recipients are not serialized.

When a specific Message is retrieved using the `getMessage()` handler method (no JSON View specified), all fields are serialized as expected:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "created" : "2014-11-14",
  "title" : "Info",
  "body" : "This is an information message",
  "author" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "firstname" : "Brian",
    "lastname" : "Clozel",
    "email" : "bclozel@pivotal.io",
    "address" : "1 Jaures street",
    "postalCode" : "69003",
    "city" : "Lyon",
    "country" : "France"
  },
  "recipients" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstname" : "Stéphane",
    "lastname" : "Nicoll",
    "email" : "snicoll@pivotal.io",
    "address" : "42 Obama street",
    "postalCode" : "1000",
    "city" : "Brussel",
    "country" : "Belgium"
  }, {
    "id" : 3,
    "firstname" : "Rossen",
    "lastname" : "Stoyanchev",
    "email" : "rstoyanchev@pivotal.io",
    "address" : "3 Warren street",
    "postalCode" : "10011",
    "city" : "New York",
    "country" : "USA"
  } ]
}
```

Only one class or interface can be specified with the `@JsonView` annotation, but you can use inheritance to represent JSON View hierarchies (if a field is part of a JSON View, it will be also part of parent view). For example, this handler method will serialize fields annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)` and `@JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)`:

```
public class View {
    interface Summary {}
    interface SummaryWithRecipients extends Summary {}
}

public class Message {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private LocalDate created;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String title;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private User author;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
    private List<User> recipients;

    private String body;
}

@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
    @RequestMapping("/with-recipients")
    public List<Message> getAllMessagesWithRecipients() {
        return messageService.getAll();
    }
}
```