# Mapping 1 table to multiple classes in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "beer")
public class Beer {

    @Id Long id;
    String brand;
    String name;
}

@Entity
public class BeerWithIngredients extends Beer {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="beer")
    List<BeerIngredient> ingredients; 
}

@Entity
public class BeerIngredient {

    @Id Long id;
    // .. whatever fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "beer_id")
    BeerWithIngredient beer;
}
```

Physically, all beer data is in one table, but I want to split it into more entities.

Please note that:

- I would not like to use discriminator column in the database
- There isn't a column that I could use for `@DiscriminatorFormula`
- I do not want to embed `Beer` inside `BeerWithIngredients`, because it essentially is not a composition, but proper inheritance

Is there a way of achieving this with JPA (Hibernate)? Right now it complains about missing discriminator column, that I don't plan to provide.

Comment: And how would you like the system to know which object to build if you refuse to provide an information by which they can be distinguished (i.e. the discriminator column). The system cannot just guess it, can it? If you have only 2 classes in your hierarchy you could use one of the "...whatever fields" in BeerIndgredient to be your discriminator column, but it will stop working once you have more subclasses. Is there any valid reason for not having extra column.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new super class `RootBeer` with all common beer properties. Annotate this class with [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html). Make `Beer` and `BeerWithIngredients` inherit from `RootBeer` and annotate them with `Entity` as well as `Table(name="beer")`.

For an example check [this](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-mappedsuperclass-hibernate).

Comment: That'd work as long as I don't need to use both Beer and BeerWithIngredients (imagine you are serving simplified Beer to a mobile client and richer BeerWithIngredients to a desktop client). Any workaround to keep using both entities?

Comment: Aren't you trying to solve this at the wrong level then? See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447922/spring-one-jpa-model-many-json-respresentations @Xorty

Comment: @Alan yeah that's quite likely - but I want to prevent unnecessary joins as well :/

Comment: Well if you don't want to write specific service calls per use case then use the Open Session in View pattern or try this new feature of Hibernate which I haven't used yet but appears to do much the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans

Comment: @Xorty right you are - I have modified my answer to make both Beer and BeerWithIngredients available to you.

Comment: @Fritz thanks again, but I am afraid that now we can't do it without discriminator column or discriminator formula on entities.

Comment: RootBeer, the parent of all beers