# Change property names while deserialzing class to JSON in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to consume a rest API call using Spring as below:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

Item item = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Item.class).getBody();
```

The response I get from the API is in following form:

```
{    
"item":[{
    "itemname": "abc",
    "qty":...
}]
}
```

The Item class has following fields:

```
Class Item{
    @JsonProperty("itemname")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("qty")
    int quantity;

    // Getter / setter methods
}
```

I've added JsonProperty annotations to the fields as their names are different from the json I get from the API. With this, I'm able to deserialize the api response successfully.

However, when I try to serialize the Item class again as a json, the field names are "itemname" and "qty". Is there any way to keep these as "name" and "quantity", and yet be able to map to the API response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are confusing serialization & deserialization. When retrieving value from external presentation - it's deserialization, when saving in external presentation - it's serialization.

Answer (score 16):

1. If you just want to serialize in different form, you can do it like this:

   ```
   public static class Item {

     private String name;
     private int quantity;

     @JsonProperty("name")
     public String getName() {
       return name;
     }

     @JsonProperty("itemname")
     public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
     }

     @JsonProperty("quantity")
     public int getQuantity() {
       return quantity;
     }

     @JsonProperty("qty")
     public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
       this.quantity = quantity;
    }
   ```

   }

   This would read `"{"itemname": "abc", "qty":10 }"` and write `"{"name": "abc", "quantity":10 }"`.

   ***But there is a big drawback - you wont be able to read `"{"name": "abc", "quantity":10 }"`, with this `ObjectMapper` (This is worse possible solution).***
2. You can use 2 `ObjectMappers` and instead of class Annotations use Mixins, to configure specific deserialization

   This is how your Mixin would look like:

   ```
   abstract public static class ItemMixin {
       ItemMixin(@JsonProperty("itemname") String itemname, @JsonProperty("qty") int qty) { }
       // note: could alternatively annotate fields "w" and "h" as well -- if so, would need to @JsonIgnore getters
       @JsonProperty("itemname") abstract String getName(); // rename property
       @JsonProperty("qty") abstract int getQuantity(); // rename property
   }
   ```

   Here is how to add Mixin in ObjectMapper.

   ```
   objectMapper.addMixIn(Item.class, ItemMixinA.class);
   ```

   ***So if you Deserialize with Mixin ObjectMapper, and serialize with standard ObjectMapper there will be no problem.***
3. You can write custom `JsonDeserialization` for your class.

   It's easy to do for class with few fields, but complexity would grow proportionally as number of fields grows.

Comment: Does Spring provide annotation based solution for mapping certain properties of one class on to another class? Just to give bit of background info, I'm writing a proxy api, which users call, and my api in turn calls a 3rd party api to fetch some data. However, the 3rd party api provides lot of data which I use for background calculation, but don't want to send to users. Also, the keys are different in the 3rd party api compared to what I want to present  to users (my original question). That's why I'm planning to map to a new class (where I hide/update properties) and send it to the users.

Comment: If you want to limit internal presentations exposure, you can use Spring @Projections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447922/spring-one-jpa-model-many-json-respresentations/28448210#28448210

Answer (score 2):

Try using @JsonAlias annotation to specify the other property names that can be used for deserializing the object. More information can be gotten from here:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html