# How to tell Hibernate criteria to skip relations in deep level?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have hibernate entity `GeUser` this entity have ManyToMany relation to `Pick` entity, this entity has OneToOne relations to `ALgo` entity and this entity has ManyToMany relation with `DbMatch` entity. My goal is get GeUser entity but without `picks.algo.matches` . I want use GeUser object on my web app, but for me data about algo matches is not required, so I want to skip it before is loaded from database.

GeUser entity:

```
...
@Entity
public class GeUser {
   ....
   @ManyToMany
   private List<Pick> picks = new ArrayList<Pick>(0);
   ...
```

Pick entity:

```
@Entity
public class Pick {
   ...
   @OneToOne
   private Algo algo;
   ...
```

Algo entity:

```
...
@Entity
public class Algo{
    ...
    // I want to skip this when GeUser entity is loading from db. Should be e.g. matches == null
    @ManyToMany
    protected List<DbMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DbMatch>(); 
    ...
```

GeUser dao method:

```
public GeUser getUser(int user_id) {

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GeUser.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user_id",user_id));

    List<GeUser> users = criteria.list();

    if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *skip relations*?

Comment: Sorry, matches should be null, GeUser.picks.get(0).algo.matches = null.

Comment: Please state the question well. What do you mean by `My goal is get GeUser entity but without last relation data`?

Comment: Edited my post, better now?

Comment: Much better! Please check out my answer, Accept if it serves the purpose. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple situation which can be solved with the help of Lazy loading. You can specify `FetchType.LAZY` `matches` inside `Algo`. `matches` will be loaded only when you access it within an active session.

```
...
@Entity
public class Algo{
    ...
    // I want to skip this when GeUser entity is loading from db. Should be e.g. matches == null
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    protected List<DbMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DbMatch>(); 
    ...
```

For more in details about Lazy loading, please follow these tutorials:

- [Stackoverflow thread - Lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate)
- [Lazy loading in hibernate](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/26/lazy-loading-in-hibernate/)
- [Lazy and Eager loading](https://dzone.com/articles/lazyeager-loading-using)

Hope it helps, feel free to comment if you need further help!

Comment: Thanks you have shown right direction for me, after read about hibernate lazy loading I understand how it work, but now I have new issue about how to not pass matches to web app using spring controller and jackson and answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746584/how-to-avoid-lazy-fetch-in-json-serialization-using-spring-data-jpa-spring-web